# Oracle hardcoded/computed column datatypes

Tags: oracle, types, calculated-columns

Is it possible to set the datatype of hardcoded or computed columns in Oracle.

For example::

```
SELECT AccountID FROM Account
```

When I read through the records returned to .Net, I can fetch the accountID using an integer.

```
_accountID = dr.GetInteger("accountID")
```

However say if I have a `UNION` query, eg:

```
SELECT AccountID FROM Account
UNION
SELECT 0 as AccountID FROM Account
```

I get an Error: `"Specified cast is not valid."` because the hardcoded 0 column can only be retrieved using a double.

```
_accountID = dr.GetDouble ("accountID")
```

Is there a way to force Oracle to return numeric computed columns as a `NUMBER(9)` or `float`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm just going to settle for using the GetDouble for integers as well as hardcoded/computed numeric columns. If anyone knows better please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

select Account_id from Account union select cast( 0 as number(9)) as Account_id from Account

or

select Account_id from Account union select cast( 0 as float(9)) as Account_id from Account